# wrong way to free a data structure

Tags: c, data-structures, memory-management, linked-list, free

I had an exam in C programming in university, one of the question in that exam was how to free a linked list data structure.

My approach was freeing the data for each node, but for no good reason I didn't get the points of that exercise.

This was my code that has not been accepted:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
  int value;
  struct node *next;
};

void free_list(struct node *head) {
  for (struct node *p = head; p != NULL; p = p->next) {
    free(p);
  }
}
```

Can someone explain what's wrong with it and what's the correct way to free linked list from memory?

Comment: how do you expect `p->next` to still be valid after `p` has been freed ?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417158/c-how-to-free-nodes-in-the-linked-list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C: How to free nodes in the linked list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417158/c-how-to-free-nodes-in-the-linked-list)

Comment: _for no good reason_ Uhem. There is a good reason as shown in the answers... ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The last part of the `for` loop is reading `p->next` *after* the body of the loop has called `free(p);`.

You need to buffer the pointer:

```
while (p != NULL)
{
  struct node * const next = p->next;
  free(p);
  p = next;
}
```

Comment: @wike instead of writing a "thank you" comment, you should [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 2):

The comment from ***Sander de Dycker*** is awesome,

Take time and you will figure out that:

`p` is freed before `p->next` is executed, so that `p->next` reads memory that has already been freed.

If you are looking for a good way to free linked list using `for loop` try this :

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
  int value;
  struct node *next;
};

void free_list(struct node *head) {
  struct node *q;
  for (struct node *p = head; p != NULL; p = q) {
    q = p->next;
    free(p);
  }
}
```

This mistake is documented in C [Bible by Dennis Ritchie](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00RLZKBYC)

Answer (score 2):

unwind hit the nail on the head. Using descriptive names makes it a bit more obvious. You want to ensure you save the pointer to be freed and then advance to the next node in your list **before** you call `free` on the saved pointer, e.g.

```
void free_list(struct node *head) 
{
    while (head) {
        struct node *victim = head;     /* save node to free */
        head = head->next;              /* advance to next before free */
        free (victim);                  /* free node */
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> Can someone explain what's wrong with it

When you have called `free` on a node, you cannot access `head->next`. You have to free `head->next` *before* `head`.

> and what's the correct way to free linked list from memory?

A pretty elegant solution is recursion. Recursion is good for making code understandable, but unless you are aware of the dangers, avoid it in production code. I often use it for prototyping. Here is an example.

```
void free_list(struct node *head) 
{
    if(head) {
        // Before freeing the first element, free the rest
        free_list(head->next)     
        // Now it's only one element left to free
        free(head);
    }
}
```

It works like this. Let's say that we have a list: `[e0, e1, e2, ..., en]`. We want to free all elements. We do that by first freeing the list `[e1, e2, ..., en]` and then free the element `e0`. Next step works the same way. We want to free `[e1, e2, ... en]`, so we start with calling the same algorithm on the list `[e2, e3, ..., en]` and when that is finished, we free `e1`. The base case is when we get an empty list `[]` in which case we do nothing.

You can also do this non-recursively. It's not as pretty, but often more efficient and it eliminates the risk of stack overflow. This is how I would have written this in production code.

```
void free_list(struct node *head) 
{
    struct node *tmp;
    while(head) {
        tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think recursion is a bad solution for this typical nonrecursive problem. Imagine your list is very long (millions of entries). You'll quickly get a stackoverflow.

Comment: recursion is a devil which should be banned from any production code.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I have added explanations about that

Comment: @P__J__ I agree, but it's good for prototyping. I have added explanations about that.

Comment: @klutt not good. Your production code may have bugs which you were not able to spot as you were using your recursion functions.

Comment: @P__J__ That's an argument you can use about literally EVERY code snippet that you change when you go from prototype to production.